# JSON/JavaScript - Getting value by passing index and property name

Tags: javascript, json, eval

For the following JSON:

```
var myJSON = 
{ "employee": [
      {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "Age": 20
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Moe",
        "Age": 35
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Mike",
        "lastName": "Poe",
        "Age": 28
      }
   ]
};
```

Let's say I need to grab a particular value by passing an index and a property name. For example, `employee[1].lastName` would give me the value "Moe". But, I'm having some rough time figuring out what's supposed to be a simple JavaScript function that takes these two values as input and returns the value as output. The following code doesn't seem to work:

```
function getValue(index, attrName) {

    var val = eval("myJSON.employee[" + index + "]." + attrName);  // is using eval() even a sound approach?
    return val;

}
```

Comment: Probably `myJSON` is not in the eval scope.

Comment: Avoid functions like eval in all programming languages, any time you can. They have their uses, but 99% of the time, there is a better way. There are good uses -- just not usually.

Comment: eval is never a sound approach. Well, almost never.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it.

```
var myJSON = 
{ "employee": [
      {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "Age": 20
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Jane",
        "lastName": "Moe",
        "Age": 35
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Mike",
        "lastName": "Poe",
        "Age": 28
      }
   ]
};

function getValue(index, attrName) {

    return myJSON['employee'][index][attrName];

}

getValue(1,'lastName')
```

Outputs: `"Moe"`.

Attribute accessors `var['attr']` and `var.attr` are identical, except that some attribute names cannot be expressed like `var.attr`. Suppose your attribute name is "foo-bar". The code `var.foo-bar` is not correct so you'd have to use `var['foo-bar']`. Also, you can address global variables with `window['var-name']`.

Comment: To elaborate for the original poster, in JavaScript dot and bracket notation are interchangeable: `obj[key] === obj.key`.

Comment: Except `obj[key]` allows key to contain spaces for example